# What's the role of this -ing phrase?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Afflicted by crushing shyness throughout childhood, I felt nurtured
>   through the ***words*** of authors who wrote in the context of their
>   communities, ***triggering images and memories of extraordinary
>   characters I longed to know and emulate***. ([Benita Porter, The Power
>   of Words](http://thisibelieve.org/essay/4210/))

It seems, to me, *words* is supplemented by this phrase, triggering ~ emulate; or modified by it. Is this right parsing?

Comment: You've got it.  The words evoked images and memories.

Comment: There's at least an argument to be made that the `authors` triggered those images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would agree with Jim, that the words (of authors) invoke images and memories.  This looks to me like the correct parsing.